# Dapp Complexity via Multiple Contracts

Tags: solidity, dapp-design

When I look at some Dapps on github there are many separate contracts that interact with each other (eg, Augur). Thus, though each contract is simple, they refer to so many others that it is quite complicated.

Is there a link to an examination of this? That is, highlighting a good Dapp with minimal or efficient use of multiple contracts, and comparing it to one that is an abomination of complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at one of my repositories: https://github.com/merlox/hydro-lottery/tree/master/contracts in there you'll find 16 contracts. It's quite overwhelming if it's the first time you're seeing it. However what I'd recommend you to do is the following:

1. Open each contract one by one and quickly read the contract and function names, you don't need to understand them, you just have to know what's in the files.
2. Then start by opening the first file that doesn't have any imports at the top, that's probably imported in other places.
3. After understanding that file, move to another that doesn't have any imports or the next simplest one that uses your imported contract and move from there. Your goal is to understand why they are importing those files and how they are used.

That way you'll begin to get a better picture of what's relevant to understand the project. Quickly you'll realize that there are 3 main contracts and the others are just helpers in my case. I've done this process many times for auditing projects so I can do it quite fast but if you haven't done it, you'll spend a good few hours wrapping your head around the contract and that's okay.